# I have a PF , how to get the list of programs that is using that particular PF?

Tags: ibm-midrange, rpgle, rpg

I have a specific physical file. How do I get a list of programs that is using that PF. Is there any command (or native utility) in AS400 which can fetch that list and give that in an outfile ?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "using"? Running applications having opened those files? Or Program objects referencing that file as described below? Are are you using embedded SQL?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The command DSPPGMREF does a pretty good job although it can take a little while to run and you have to query the output of the command to find the usages.   There are also a quite a few config parameters which alter the type of data the command produces.

Basically, the command is run over all the programs and it compiles all the usages (Files, data areas, display files etc) and writes those to a file which can be queried to find the particular file in question.

```
DSPPGMREF   PGM(LIBRARY/*ALL)  OUTPUT(*OUTFILE)
            OUTFILE(QTEMP/OUTFILE)
```

[IBM DSPPGMREF command](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/i/7.1?topic=ssw_ibm_i_71/cl/dsppgmref.htm)